# Python, How to Roll a Pose Bone along a Vector in PoseMode?

Tags: python, bones, pose-mode, quaternion

I'm stuck, Trying to roll a pose bone while staying in the Head and Tail vector. When I use axis angle or any other rotation, it doesn't stay in place and it goes off its vector.

Vector shouldn't change and rolling angle is the variable.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rolling a pose bone.**

[Using python, how do you get the "roll" of a pose_bone?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165742/using-python-how-do-you-get-the-roll-of-a-pose-bone)

IMO this is simply a case of rotating the bone around any pivot point that is on a line parallel to  y axis vector passing thru points head and tail.

[Matrix math to translate, rotate, scale with respect to a pivot point in Object mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194796/matrix-math-to-translate-rotate-scale-with-respect-to-a-pivot-point-in-object)

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix


def rollposebone(pb, roll):
    R = (
         Matrix.Translation(pb.head) @ 
         Matrix.Rotation(roll, 4, pb.y_axis) @
         Matrix.Translation(-pb.head)
         )
    pb.matrix = R @ pb.matrix


# test call, roll 3 degrees.
from math import radians
context = bpy.context
    
rollposebone(context.active_pose_bone, radians(3))
```

Please also note that blender  natively uses radians, as does `math` and `numpy`. Recommend using as above, *ie* if you wish to pass a value like 90 degrees pass via `radians(90)` rather than converting to and fro in code.  If making a UI give any angle property a `unit = 'ROTATION`` and it will be displayed in the chosen rotation unit, which is by default degrees.

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy
import math
import numpy as np
from mathutils import Vector 

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
RobloxRig = bpy.context.scene.objects['__Rig'] 
UpperRightArm_bone = RobloxRig.pose.bones["RightUpperArm"]


def angle(v1, v2, acute):
# v1 is your first vector
# v2 is your second vector
    angle = np.arccos(np.dot(v1, v2) / (np.linalg.norm(v1) * np.linalg.norm(v2)))
    if (acute == True):
        return angle
    else:
        return 2 * np.pi - angle
    
def RollBone(bone,Degrees):
    vdir = Vector(bone.tail - bone.head)
    BoneXVec = Vector((0,vdir.y,vdir.z))
    Xangle = math.degrees(angle(Vector((0, 0, 1)), BoneXVec, True))

    xAbs = vdir.y 
    xsign = 0

    if xAbs > 0:
        xsign = -math.radians(Xangle)
    
    if xAbs < 0:
        xsign = math.radians(Xangle)

    #Center X
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value= xsign, orient_axis='X', orient_type='GLOBAL')

    bpy.context.view_layer.update()

    vdir = Vector(bone.tail - bone.head)
    BoneXVec = Vector((vdir.x,0,vdir.z))
    Yangle = math.degrees(angle(Vector((1, 0, 0)), BoneXVec, True))
    yAbs = vdir.z 
    ysign = 0

    if yAbs > 0:
        ysign = -math.radians(Yangle) + math.radians(90)
    
    if yAbs < 0:
        ysign = math.radians(Yangle)  + math.radians(90)
   
    #Center Y
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=ysign, orient_axis='Y', orient_type='GLOBAL')
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
    
    #Roll on Z
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=math.radians(Degrees), orient_axis='Z', orient_type='GLOBAL')
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
    
    #Return Rotation
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-ysign, orient_axis='Y', orient_type='GLOBAL')
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value= -xsign, orient_axis='X', orient_type='GLOBAL')




if __name__ == "__main__":
    RollBone(UpperRightArm_bone,90)
```

I used bpy.ops.transform.rotate to rotate the bone to its normal x and y vector, then I rotate z to the desired angle. Lastly I use the inverse of x and y rotations to set it back to the space it was at.